# I made some custom changes to template files in my wordpress parent theme. How do i make sure they are not overwritten when theme gets updated?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

This is the code that is inside a php template. But this will be overwritten when i update the theme because the change is made in the mother theme files.

Is is possible to put this code inside the functions.php child theme file? Or do i have to copy the template files into my child theme? What is the best way to go about keeping these changes for the future?
One of the modifications that is made is the code below which just hides an element based upon user-roles in my single listing page.

```
<?php
/**
 * `Call now` quick action.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */

if ( ! ( $phone = $listing->get_field('phone') ) )
    return;

// if you want to not display anything for guests
if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    return;

// if you want to not display anything for anyone but administrator or subscriber
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) && !in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) 
    return;

$link = sprintf( 'tel:%s', $phone );
?>

<li id="<?php echo esc_attr( $action['id'] ) ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $action['class'] ) ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ) ?>" rel="nofollow">
        <?php echo c27()->get_icon_markup( $action['icon'] ) ?>
        <span><?php echo $action['label'] ?></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Would appreciate any help with this.

Here is a screenshot of the file if its needed, im not sure:

[image: the php file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the parent theme uses the [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function to load its partials/templates (as it should, eg. `get_template_part( 'templates/single-listing/quick-actions/call-now' );`), then all you need to do is copy the `templates` folder from your parent theme into your child theme and edit the `call-now.php` file there.

Comment: Ok i cant find if that code is somewhere in the files. So im just gonna copy the templates folder and hope it works